# Creating areas that are within fixed range from specific amount of points using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile of thousands of points with ID's and coordinates (representing buildings in the countryside). Some of these points are in clear clusters near each others, some are in line formations (buildings following roads) and some are on their own with just few neighboring points around them. Some are almost a part of larger clusters but are a barely out of them.

I'm trying to create as large polygon-areas as possible around, near or in the middle of these points, where you can reach at least six points within 200 meters even from the furthest edge of these polygons. Picture below:

[image]

(Left picture: Two black dots represent furthest places that can be reached from all the points within 200 meters. The grey area is the desired outcome, from which you can reach all six points within 200 meters anywhere in it.

Right picture: A seventh point in the similar situation would spread the desired area towards it, while the overall grey area is still reachable from at least six points within 200 meters)

I've tried creating buffers for all points and then combining the ones that are overlapping and studying the centers of these areas, but this way I can't enforce either the six point minimun or 200 meter distance criterias. Another problem is, that if a seventh point is nearby, I would like it to be taken into consideration (as shown in the picture). Basically, the reachable area would get larger in this situation

Originally, I thought this was a fairly simple procedure, but I can't seem to find a suitable tool or method for this type of work.

How could I these areas using QGIS?

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, you can achieve this by first buffering all points by 200 metres, then selecting all areas where at least 6 buffer circles overlap (in QGIS you can use [kgjenkin's "Count Polygon Overlap" processing model](https://github.com/kgjenkins/qgis-count-polygon-overlap) for this), and then dissolving the selected areas.

Comment: See here, maybe it can give some ideas? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408552/88814 and here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419732/88814